# questions about url parameters in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm pretty new to Jersey. I'm trying to use GET and some parameters to retrieve data. url is something like "http://www.example.com/products?searchKeyword=tv". I have two questions here.

1. Since I have the parameter searchKeyword in my query, do I need to use `@Consume` annotation? If not, in which case `@Consume` is supposed to be used?
2. To get the parameter in query, should I use `@QueryParam` or `@Context HttpServletRequest` or `@Context Uri`, I guess in this case, I should use `@QueryParam`. If so, when should I use the other two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no `@Consume` annotation. I assume you mean `@Consumes`. That annotation doesn't  have anything to do with query parameters. It's used for [content type negotiation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html#6nmq2cp2i):

   > The `@Consumes` annotation is used to specify which MIME media types of representations a resource can accept, or consume, from the client.
2. Yes, you should use `@QueryParam`. It's [the simplest thing that could possibly work.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork) You want a query parameter value? `@QueryParam` is built expressly for that. Why wouldn't you use it?

   > If so, when should I use the other two?

   Use `@Context HttpServletRequest` and `@Context URI` when you actually need to use those more-complex objects. Sure, you *could* get a query parameter value out of those, but that is a common-enough task that they gave you a shortcut. `@QueryParam` is for getting query parameter values. [`@Context` is for getting other things.](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2408)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I have one more question regarding Consumes. Does that mean Consume is only used when the request has a message body, for example, When I use PUT or POST method. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, GET requests doesn't consume any content. It's just URL with custom params, but the parameters relate to URL, not to the content in HTTP request.